# Why does const_cast<iterator>(const_iterator) work in Visual C++ 6.0, but not in Visual Studio .NET?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, iterator, constants

I am trying to modernize some old C++ code. It was originally built in Visual C++ 6.0. My current approach is to Step through the versions of Visual Studio one at a time to minimize how much of the code breaks per iteration.

Take the following example:

```
vector<someType>::iterator someFunction(...){
    vector<someType>::const_iterator someConstIterator;
    ...
    return (const_cast<vector<someType>::iterator>(someConstIterator));
}
```

In Visual C++ 6.0, it compiles just fine. In Visual Studio .NET, I get the following error:

> error C2440: 'const_cast': cannot convert from
>   'vector::const_iterator' to 'vector::iterator'

What has changed? Is it a library change? A C++ version change?

Comment: It could be that in Visual C++ 6.0, `vector<T>::iterator` was defined as `T*` (which it is allowed, but not required to be), and `vector<T>::const_iterator` was defined as `T const*` (which it is allowed, but not required to be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `const_cast<T>` is allowed under four specific circumstances [listed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), you cannot generally convert

```
vector<T>::const_iterator
```

to

```
vector<T>::iterator
```

unless the source and target types are pointers or types that differ only in cv-qualification.

Since `vector<T>::const_iterator` could not be defined as `const vector<T>::iterator` because `vector<T>::const_iterator` needs to remain changeable, the only reasonable explanation is that both `vector<T>::const_iterator` and `vector<T>::iterator` were typedef-ed as pointers in the Visual C++ 6.0 library, but the library that ships with Visual Studio .NET has changed.